# Como iterar por objetos com nesting indeterminado

Tags: php

Tenho uma classe chamada `Document`. Cada `Document` pode ser filho de um `Document` ou *parent* de um `Document`. Cada `Document` só pode ter um *parent* e pode ter inúmeros filhos.

Estou tentando escrever uma função `Document->parentLevel()` para descobrir quantos níveis de hierarquia (máximo) existem abaixo desse `Document`.

Por exemplo:

```
                     Doc1 
       Doc2          Doc3         Doc4
   Doc5    Doc 6
Doc7
```

Ao rodar `Doc1->parentlevel()` a função retornaria 3, pois o maior número de níveis hierárquicos abaixo dele é 3 (`Doc2->Doc5->Doc7`).

Os objetos possuem uma função `Document->hasChildren()` que retorna `true` ou `false` se o objeto tem filhos e uma função `Document->children()` que retorna uma `array` com os filhos desse objeto.

Meu código até agora:

```
public function parentLevel($startLevel = 0)
    {
        $level = $startLevel;
        $active = $this;
        while ($active->hasChildren()) {
            $level++;
            foreach ($children as $child) {
                if ($child->hasChildren()) {
                    $level2 = $child->parentLevel();
                    if ($level2 > $level) {
                        $level = $level2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $level;
    }
```

Comment: Você precisará saber quais são os nós no maior ramo ou apenas o número?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se não precisar saber quais são os nós que fazem parte do maior ramo, basta fazer:

```
public function parentLevel ()
{
    $level = 0;

    if ($this->hasChildren())
    {
        $childrenLevels = [];

        foreach($this->children() as $child)
        {
            $childrenLevels[] = $child->parentLevel();
        }

        $level = max($childrenLevels) + 1;
    }

    return $level;
}
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/6L6vU0).

Basicamente, se o nó possuir filhos, busca-se o filho que possui o maior valor de `parentLevel` e incrementa em 1, caso contrário, retorna 0.